# Cannot remove package phpoffice/phpword. (laravel 5.2)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've been working on a Laravel project. While I'm trying to install some package. I got warned

> Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
>   Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.

Therefore, I executed the command

```
composer remove phpoffice/phpexcel
```

The phpoffice/phpexcel has been remove from composer.json successfully.

Then install the package,

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

I still got warned by the same warning,

> Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
>   Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.

I always got warned by this sentence from every composer command even the phpoffice/phpexcel has been removed from composer.json.

Pls help I really have no idea to remove this warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the package `phpoffice/phpexcel` is used by another package in your composer.json. To see if that's the case you can use the following command to find out which other packages may need `phpoffice/phpexcel`:

```
composer why phpoffice/phpexcel
```

Does that give you a list of packages or an error?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error you can run the following commands --

composer remove phpoffice/phpexcel

Then -

composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Then -
composer dump-autoload

composer update